# Entity FrameWork in Wpf Code First

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism

Can any one give me example to implement Entity frame work with repository pattern in WPF... Using Code First. Currently i am using but data is not saving. Entity state.Added is null.

Comment: Could you specify "data is not saving" part in more detail? The save context is failing or nothing is failing but data does not apepar in DB or else ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example from MSDN. It comes with video as well as text explanation. A good point to start: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx